# Run a simple sql group by query in kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to run a simple sql group by query in kibana 4 "Discover" page.
Each record in my elastic search index represent a log and has 3 columns: `process_id (not unique value), log_time, log_message`.

example:

process_id                log_time             log_message

----------------         --------------------                --------------------

1                        2014/12/11 01:00              msg1

1                        2014/12/11 01:10           msg2

1                        2014/12/11 01:20           msg3

2                        2014/12/11 11:00           msg4

2                        2014/12/11 11:10           msg5

I want to generate a table in kibana that looks like:

process_id         first log_time                              last log_time

----------------        ------------------------          --------------------

1                    2014/12/11 01:00         2014/12/11 01:20

2                    2014/12/11 11:00        2014/12/11 11:10

In sql the query is simple: 
select process_id, max(log_time), min(log_time)
from logs_table
group by process_id

How can I run this query in Kibana? Is it possible to run the query in "Discover" page or should I create a panel (Visualize page)?

thanks.

Comment: Have you found the solution to it or should i share the solution?

Comment: No, still searching...meanwhile I move to splunk

Comment: @JohnRambo Which version of Kibana do you run?

Answer (score 16):

I'm on Kibana 4.3, but this is possible on any version of Kibana. You need to create a Visualization panel of type Data Table.

Before that you need to make sure that you've created an index pattern for your index, such as this one, with the `log_time` date field as the timestamp for your index.

[image]

Then you can create your Data Table visualization and it must look like this, i.e. a split rows `terms` aggregation on the `process_id` field and then two metrics aggregation (one `min` and one `max`) on the `log_time` date field

[image]

Finally, your results will look like this as expected:

[image]

Comment: Dear Val, please kindly answer my question, 
max can be used to choose top 1 value, but how to choose top n value. like in sql we might do : choose top 5 value ``SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 5``

Comment: @yuliansen Please create a new question (maybe referencing this one) which explains your context and needs

Comment: please kindly check out ``https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115037/query-top-n-value-in-kibana``